# In an induction step after having establised the base case, May one prove $p(k+1)\implies p(k+2)$ instead of $p(k)\implies p(k+1)$?

Tags: induction

I picked up on the fact that a proof I was working on could be more easily made: it would involve less lines, If we proved as our induction step $p(k+1)\implies p(k+2)$. I stay on top of the multiple variations of the principle of mathematical induction so I was wondering whether this could be one of those or not.

Comment: Yes, of course....

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh, thank you!

Comment: Whether you call the integer $k$ or $k+1$ is irrelevant.  What's important is that the inductive step progress from a positive integer to *the next* integer.

Answer (score 1):

Put $m=k+1$ to see that $m+1=k+2$

So, $p(k+1)\implies p(k+2)$ is equivalent to $p(m)\implies p(m+1)$ which is equivalent to $p(k)\implies p(k+1)$

So, you can of course go for $p(k+1)\implies p(k+2)$